# How to dynamically retrieve and display data based on input from google forms

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

To be very specific, let's say I have a google form where it asks you your name (text box) and how much do you like carrots, with a multiple choice prompt of "very much" and "I hate them!"

After the user submits their choice on that page of the survey, I want the next page to display text that refers to their choice. For example, IF they select "very much", then "I love carrots too, [insert name]! Do you want to see my favorite recipes?" If they select "I hate them!", I want it to say "Fair enough [insert name], we'll stay away from carrots!"

This is a simplified version of what I want to achieve, as there will be many IF/THEN statements that I will want to be retrievable depending on the combination of inputs. FOr example, the next question might be "Do you like soups?" And if they answered yes to carrots and yes to soups, they would be displayed one set of text, and if they answered yes to one and no to the other it would be different.

Importantly, I am not trying to actually change the context of the form questions based on the responses. I just want their to be a text field that populates based on their answers, pulling from a spreadsheet that I have populated with the appropriate text to retrieve depending on their answers to the survey.

Of course, I understand I may be going at this entirely wrong and appreciate any and all advice. Some context, I am trying to develop a proof of concept so I am looking for the simplest solution for someone with little to no programming knowledge rather than an elegant or scaleable solution.

I do understand the skip logic option in surveys. My hope is that given my desired level of complexity, i.e., with 10-12 multiple choice questions (4-5 choices per question) as well as a few free text questions (which in and of themselves make skip logic not feasible as solution) there might be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

From the question

> After the user submits their choice on that page of the survey, I want
> the next page to display text that refers to their choice.

This is not possible with the Google Apps Script Forms Service but could be done using other services.

## Explanation

The Forms Service from [Google Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start) could be used to create, access, and modify Google Forms and to read and edit form responses <s>but not to control the forms UI at run time</s>. Url Fetch and Html service could be used to edit the control the forms UI at run time. For further details see [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/101809/88163) recent answer from me to a similar question.